# how to specify dynamic scope object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a html code

```html
<tr ng-repeat='row in po123'>
           <td>{{row.buyerLineItemNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{row.buyerPartNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{row.supplierPartNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{row.itemDescription}}</td>
           <td>{{row.itemQuantity}}</td>
           <td>{{row.itemQuantityUOM}}</td>
           </tr>
```

and a scope element

```html
var poNumber = "123";
$scope.poNumber = poNumber;
 $scope["po"+poNumber] = [{'buyerLineItemNumber':'12121','buyerPartNumber':'buyerPartNumber','supplierPartNumber':'supplierPartNumber','itemDescription':'itemDescription','itemDescription':'itemDescription','itemQuantityUOM':'itemQuantityUOM'}];
```

In the appication poNumber is dynamically generated and is available as a $scope value and i create a dynamic scope element using the poNumber . How can i use this dynamic created scope element in ng-repeat.

if i specify statically as in the code snippet it works fine, i want to specify something like`<tr ng-repeat='row in "po"+{{poNumber}}'>`

how can i achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It should be controller responsability to decide which data will be displayed not the view, what stops you to making the dynamic selection in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

First:

```
var poNumber = "123";
$scope.poNumber = poNumber;
$scope.myData = {};
$scope.myData["po"+poNumber] = [{'buyerLineItemNumber':'12121','buyerPartNumber':'buyerPartNumber','supplierPartNumber':'supplierPartNumber','itemDescription':'itemDescription','itemDescription':'itemDescription','itemQuantityUOM':'itemQuantityUOM'}];
```

and html:

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in myData["po"+poNumber]'>
```

Second:

```
// add to controller
$scope.getByName = function (value) { 
  return $scope[value]
};
```

and html:

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in getByName("po"+poNumber)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you are using poNumber as an id for each data in your scope, you only need to use an array of objects for that.

If you set:

```
$scope.myArray = [];
```

and whenever you want to add a new object with buyer data, you just have to do the next inside of a function or a method or a listener in the controller, it depends on what you will need:

```
var newBuyerData ={
'buyerLineItemNumber':'12121',
'buyerPartNumber':buyerPartNumber,
'supplierPartNumber':supplierPartNumber,
'itemDescription':itemDescription,
'itemDescription':itemDescription,
'itemQuantityUOM':itemQuantityUOM};

$scope.myArray.push(newBuyerData);
```

And then you will have an array with al the objects you want to show and then you will be able to do the ng-repeat, because is used for that type of data, the ng-repeat instanciate each item in a collection of data.

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in myArray'>
           <td>{{row.buyerLineItemNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{row.buyerPartNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{row.supplierPartNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{row.itemDescription}}</td>
           <td>{{row.itemQuantity}}</td>
           <td>{{row.itemQuantityUOM}}</td>
 </tr>
```

With this you will be able to have a list of buyers data with all the data listed as you want.

On the other way, if you only want to show just 1 buyer, you can still have the array of buyers data and just add it a field called id (element_id) generated randombly, it'll be something like this:

```
var idNumber = 1000;

var newBuyerData ={
'element_id': idNubmer,
'buyerLineItemNumber':'12121',
'buyerPartNumber':buyerPartNumber,
'supplierPartNumber':supplierPartNumber,
'itemDescription':itemDescription,
'itemDescription':itemDescription,
'itemQuantityUOM':itemQuantityUOM};

$scope.myArray.push(newBuyerData);
idNumber = idNumber + 1;
```

this part should be inside of a method or function.So, whenever you call it it'll add the new data to the array and then will increase the idNumber variable.

And then you can just search the data you want and show only 1 buyer data item.

```
var itemThatIWant = 123; //the number that i want, you can insert this //number with an input text or something

$scope.itemToShow = "";
 angular.forEach($scope.myArray,function(item){
    if(item.idNumber === itemThatIWant){
      $scope.itemToShow = item;
    }
});
```

And then in your html you will not need the ng-repeat, you can just use your itemToShow variable:

```
<tr >
           <td>{{itemToShow.buyerLineItemNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{itemToShow.buyerPartNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{itemToShow.supplierPartNumber}}</td>
           <td>{{itemToShow.itemDescription}}</td>
           <td>{{itemToShow.itemQuantity}}</td>
           <td>{{itemToShow.itemQuantityUOM}}</td>
</tr>
```

I hope it helps :)